# Same data when connection to multiple wsdl clients using zeep

Tags: python, wsdl, zeep

I'm trying to connect to two different wsdl's using zeep and printing the operations.
When I connect to the first client and print I get the correct respons, but when I then connect to the second I get the same operations.

I can get the data if I connect with one client, then restart the database and skip the first client and connect with the second.

```
from zeep.client import Client

localDPClient = Client("http://localhost/StorageManager/?wsdl")
print([method for method, value in localDPClient.service.__dict__["_operations"].items()])

localDPClient2 = Client("http://localhost/CableBoxManager/?wsdl")
print([method for method, value in localDPClient2.service.__dict__["_operations"].items()])
```

Output

```
['ImportArtifacts', 'ImportBundles', 'ExportArtifacts', 'ExportBundles', 'ReadArtifactsFromTypes']
['ImportArtifacts', 'ImportBundles', 'ExportArtifacts', 'ExportBundles', 'ReadArtifactsFromTypes']
```

Expected output

```
['ImportArtifacts', 'ImportBundles', 'ExportArtifacts', 'ExportBundles', 'ReadArtifactsFromTypes'
['IdentifyBox', 'IdentifyCable', 'ReadCable', 'ReadCableDefinition', 'ReadAllCableFeatures', 'ReadBox']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by adding more parameters

```
localDPClient = Client("http://localhost/StorageManager/?wsdl", service_name="StorageManager", port_name=f"WSHttpBinding_IStorageManager")

localDPClient2 = Client("http://localhost/CableBoxManager/?wsdl", service_name="CableBoxManager", port_name=f"WSHttpBinding_ICableBoxManager")
```